# Would I be a resident alien or dual-status alien for tax purposes in 2017?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, dual-status

**Background**: I came to the US in Aug 2013, to pursue my Master's degree. After graduating in Dec 2014, I worked for a company in Michigan from Feb 2015 to July 2017. Starting from Aug 2017, I have come back to school in Michigan to pursue my PhD. I have been on an F1 visa from Aug 2013 to Oct 2016, H1B visa from Oct 2016 to July 2017, and then F1 visa again starting from Aug 2017 onwards.

**Questions**:

1) For tax year 2017, I definitely meet the Substantial Presence Test (> 183 days on H1B visa) which makes me a residential alien for tax purposes. Since I came back to an F1 visa, does that make me a non-resident alien for the rest of 2017 (and hence, a dual-status alien)?

2) If yes, is there a software which handles the dual-status well? Or should I just generate 2 returns (1040/1040-NR) separately and mail them together?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) For tax year 2017, I definitely meet the Substantial Presence Test
>   (> 183 days on H1B visa) which makes me a residential alien for tax
>   purposes. Since I came back to an F1 visa, does that make me a
>   non-resident alien for the rest of 2017 (and hence, a dual-status
>   alien)?

Since you pass the Substantial Presence Test for 2017, you are a resident alien for all of 2017.

Although this is your first year of residency (you were a resident alien for 2016), the [First Year of Residency](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2017_publink1000222164) rules don't change anything because they say you start being a resident on the first day you were present in the US in 2017, and I presume you were in the US in the beginning of 2017.

The [Last Year of Residency](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2017_publink1000222182) rules couldn't possibly apply, since you will be a resident alien for 2018 also (you are not an "exempt individual" as a [student](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2017_publink1000222143) for your days on F1 if you have been an "exempt individual" for some part of 5 previous calendar years, and you have already been an "exempt individual" as a student for some part of 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, and 2017).

So you are not dual-status, and you are a resident alien for all of 2017.